# JavaScript anagram comparison

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare two strings to see if they are anagrams.

My problem is that I'm only comparing the first letter in each string. For example, "Mary" and "Army" will return true but unfortunately so will "Mary" and Arms."

How can I compare each letter of both strings before returning true/false?

Here's a jsbin demo (click the "Console" tab to see the results"):

http://jsbin.com/hasofodi/1/edit

```
function compare (a, b) {
  y = a.split("").sort();
  z = b.split("").sort();
  for (i=0; i<y.length; i++) {
    if(y.length===z.length) {
      if (y[i]===z[i]){
        console.log(a + " and " + b + " are anagrams!");
        break;
      }
      else {
        console.log(a + " and " + b + " are not anagrams.");
        break;
      }
    }
    else {
      console.log(a + " has a different amount of letters than " + b);
    }
    break;
  }
}

compare("mary", "arms");
```

Comment: Always remember to declare your variables!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Instead of comparing letter by letter, after sorting you can `join` the arrays to strings again, and let the browser do the comparison:

```
function compare (a, b) {
    var y = a.split("").sort().join(""),
        z = b.split("").sort().join("");
    console.log(z === y
        ? a + " and " + b + " are anagrams!"
        : a + " and " + b + " are not anagrams."
    );
}
```

Comment: `console.log(a + " and " + b " are " + (z === y ? "anagrams!" : "not anagrams."));` much shorter

Comment: This solution is perfect if you are comparing two words only. If you use it inside a loop, the second iteration will already make this expensive, because you're comparing two whole words. The ideal solution is to make a couple of checks before and after the `word.split("").sort().join("")` bit.

Comment: This is cleanest solution but is it the most optimized solution, considering the built in function of Javascript for split ,sort and join, how efficient is it going to be if we calculate the BigO for it.  @Oriol

Comment: This code breaks if  we have different casing.
for eg. a  = "Bad Credit"  , b = "Debit Card"

Answer (score 6):

If you want to write a function, without using inbuilt one, Check the below solution.

```
function isAnagram(str1, str2) {

  if(str1 === str2) {
    return true;
  }

  let srt1Length = str1.length;
  let srt2Length = str2.length;

  if(srt1Length !== srt2Length) {
    return false;
  }

  var counts = {};

  for(let i = 0; i < srt1Length; i++) {
    let index = str1.charCodeAt(i)-97;
    counts[index] = (counts[index] || 0) + 1;
  }

  for(let j = 0; j < srt2Length; j++) {
    let index = str2.charCodeAt(j)-97;
    if (!counts[index]) { 
      return false; 
    }
    counts[index]--;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: This one is great because you aren't sorting which means it's more efficient.

Comment: @ raja-sekar - Works great, can you explain a bit more on  what the logic is doing

Comment: 1. Define hash 2. Increase the count for first string. 3. Decrease the count for second string. If letter in string 2 not found in the hash then return false. 4. else return true.

Comment: What does "charCodeAt(i)-97" do?

Comment: charCodeAt of a is 97, so 97-97 will be zero. It will give a=0, b-1, c=2...

Answer (score 4):

This considers case sensitivity and removes white spaces AND ignore all non-alphanumeric characters

```js
function compare(a,b) {
    var c = a.replace(/\W+/g, '').toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");
    var d = b.replace(/\W+/g, '').toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");
        return (c ===d) ? "Anagram":"Not anagram";
}
```

Comment: Can you tell him also where is his mistake so he can learn from it?

Answer (score 4):

Quick one-liner solution with javascript functions - [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)(), [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)(), [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)() and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)():

- Convert input string to lowercase
- Make array of the string with split()
- Sort the array alphabetically
- Now join the sorted array into a string using join()

Do the above steps to both strings and if after sorting strings are the same then it will be anargam.

```js
// Return true if two strings are anagram else return false

function Compare(str1, str2){
     if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
        return false
     }
  
    return str1.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("") === str2.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("")
}

console.log(Compare("Listen", "Silent")) //true
console.log(Compare("Mary", "arms")) //false
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for sorting, splitting, or joining. The following two options are efficient ways to go:

```
//using char array for fast lookups
const Anagrams1 = (str1 = '', str2 = '') => {
    if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    
    if (str1 === str2) {
        return true;
    }

    const charCount = [];
    let startIndex = str1.charCodeAt(0);

    for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        const charInt1 = str1.charCodeAt(i);
        const charInt2 = str2.charCodeAt(i); 

        startIndex = Math.min(charInt1, charInt2);
        
        charCount[charInt1] = (charCount[charInt1] || 0) + 1;           
        charCount[charInt2] = (charCount[charInt2] || 0) - 1;           
    }

    while (charCount.length >= startIndex) { 
        if (charCount.pop()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

console.log(Anagrams1('afc','acf'))//true
console.log(Anagrams1('baaa','bbaa'))//false
console.log(Anagrams1('banana','bananas'))//false
console.log(Anagrams1('',' '))//false
console.log(Anagrams1(9,'hey'))//false

//using {} for fast lookups
function Anagrams(str1 = '', str2 = '') {
  if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  if (str1 === str2) {
    return true;
  }

  const lookup = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    const char1 = str1[i];
    const char2 = str2[i];
    const remainingChars = str1.length - (i + 1);
    
    lookup[char1] = (lookup[char1] || 0) + 1;
    lookup[char2] = (lookup[char2] || 0) - 1;

    if (lookup[char1] > remainingChars || lookup[char2] > remainingChars) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    if (lookup[str1[i]] !== 0 || lookup[str2[i]] !== 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(Anagrams('abc', 'cba'));//true
console.log(Anagrams('abcc', 'cbaa')); //false
console.log(Anagrams('abc', 'cde')); //false
console.log(Anagrams('aaaaaaaabbbbbb','bbbbbbbbbaaaaa'));//false
console.log(Anagrams('banana', 'ananab'));//true
```

Comment: Just booleans are not enough for this, for example: `Anagrams("baaa", "bbaa")` returns true, but should clearly return false. In that respect [Cracked679](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198790/1045510) got the idea right but their code is a bit messier.

Comment: @Kroltan That's a good point. I have modified the code to account for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Cleanest and most efficient solution for me

```js
function compare(word1, word2) {
  const { length } = word1

  if (length !== word2.length) {
    return false
  }
  
  const charCounts = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const char1 = word1[i]
    const char2 = word2[i]

    charCounts[char1] = (charCounts[char1] || 0) + 1
    charCounts[char2] = (charCounts[char2] || 0) - 1
  }

  for (const char in charCounts) {
    if (charCounts[char]) {
      return false
    }
  }

  return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your function to work.

It will loop through each letter of both words UNTIL a letter doesn't match (then it knows that they AREN'T anagrams).

It will only work for words that have the same number of letters and that are perfect anagrams.

```
function compare (a, b) {
  y = a.split("").sort();
  z = b.split("").sort();
  areAnagrams = true;
  for (i=0; i<y.length && areAnagrams; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    if(y.length===z.length) {
      if (y[i]===z[i]){
        // good for now
        console.log('up to now it matches');
      } else {
        // a letter differs
        console.log('a letter differs');
        areAnagrams = false;
      }
    }
    else {
      console.log(a + " has a different amount of letters than " + b);
      areAnagrams = false;
    }

  }
  if (areAnagrams) {
    console.log('They ARE anagrams');
  } else {
    console.log('They are NOT anagrams');
  }
    return areAnagrams;
}

compare("mary", "arms");
```

Answer (score 1):

A more modern solution without sorting.

```
function(s, t) {
 if(s === t) return true
 if(s.length !== t.length) return false

 let count = {}

 for(let letter of s)
  count[letter] = (count[letter] || 0) + 1

 for(let letter of t) { 
  if(!count[letter]) return false
  else --count[letter]
 }

 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function validAnagramOrNot(a, b) {
      if (a.length !== b.length)
      return false;
      const lookup = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          let character = a[i];
          lookup[character] = (lookup[character] || 0) + 1;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
          let character = b[i];
          if (!lookup[character]) {
            return false;
          } else {
             lookup[character]--;
          }
       }
  return true;
}
 validAnagramOrNot("a", "b"); // false
 validAnagramOrNot("aza", "zaa"); //true
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my contribution, I had to do this exercise for a class! I'm finally understanding how JS works, and as I was able to came up with a solution (it's not - by far - the best one, but it's ok!) I'm very happy I can share this one here, too! (although there are plenty solutions here already, but whatever :P )

```
function isAnagram(string1, string2) {
    // first check: if the lenghts are different, not an anagram 
    if (string1.length != string2.length)
        return false
    else {
    // it doesn't matter if the letters are capitalized, 
    // so the toLowerCase method ensures that...
        string1 = string1.toLowerCase()
        string2 = string2.toLowerCase()
        
    // for each letter in the string (I could've used for each :P)
        for (let i = 0; i < string1.length; i++) {
            // check, for each char in string2, if they are NOT somewhere at string1
            if (!string1.includes(string2.charAt(i))) {
                return false
            }
            else {
                // if all the chars are covered 
                // and the condition is the opposite of the previous if
                if (i == (string1.length - 1))
                    return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar approach with filter function

```js
const str1 = 'triangde'

const str2 = 'integral'

const st1 = str1.split('')
const st2 = str2.split('')

const item = st1.filter((v)=>!st2.includes(v))

const result = item.length === 0 ? 'Anagram' : 'Not anagram' + ' Difference - ' + item;

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function compare (a, b) {
  y = a.split("").sort();
  z = b.split("").sort();
  if(y.length==z.length) {
   for (i=0; i<y.length; i++) {
    if (y[i]!==z[i]){
     console.log(a + " and " + b + " are not anagrams!");
     return false;
    }
   }
   return true;
  } else { return false;}}
```

compare("mary", "arms");

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can do the length check before the for loop, no need to do it for each character...

Also, "break" breaks the whole for loop. If you use "continue" instead of "break", it skips the current step. 
That is why only the first letters are compared, after the first one it quits the for loop.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Make the function return false if the length between words differ and if it finds a character between the words that doesn't match.

```
// check if two strings are anagrams
var areAnagrams = function(a, b) {
    // if length is not the same the words can't be anagrams
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;
    // make words comparable
    a = a.split("").sort().join("");
    b = b.split("").sort().join("");
    // check if each character match before proceeding
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if ((a.charAt(i)) != (b.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // all characters match!
    return true;
};
```

It is specially effective when one is iterating through a big dictionary array, as it compares the first letter of each "normalised" word before proceeding to compare the second letter - and so on. If one letter doesn't match, it jumps to the next word, **saving a lot of time**.

In a dictionary with 1140 words (not all anagrams), the whole check was done 70% faster than if using the method in the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

an anagram with modern javascript that can be use in nodejs. This will take into consideration empty strings, whitespace and case-sensitivity. Basically takes an array or a single string as input. It relies on sorting the input string and then looping over the list of words and doing the same and then comparing the strings to each other. It's very efficient. A more efficient solution may be to create a trie data structure and then traversing each string in the list. looping over the two words to compare strings is slower than using the built-in string equality check.

The function does not allow the same word as the input to be considered an anagram, as it is not an anagram. ;) useful edge-case.

```
const input = 'alerting';
const list1 = 'triangle';
const list2 = ['', ' ', 'alerting', 'buster', 'integral', 'relating', 'no', 'fellas', 'triangle', 'chucking'];

const isAnagram = ((input, list) => {
  if (typeof list === 'string') {
    list = [list];
  }

  const anagrams = [];
  const sortedInput = sortWord(input).toLowerCase();
  const inputLength = sortedInput.length;
  list.forEach((element, i) => {
    if ( inputLength === element.length && input !== element ) {
      const sortedElement = sortWord(element).toLowerCase();
      if ( sortedInput === sortedElement) {
        anagrams.push(element);
      }
    }
  });

  return anagrams;
})

const sortWord = ((word) => {
  return word.split('').sort().join('');
});

console.log(`anagrams for ${input} are: ${isAnagram(input, list1)}.`);
console.log(`anagrams for ${input} are: ${isAnagram(input, list2)}.`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple algorithm:
1. Remove all unnecessary characters
2. make objects of each character
3. check to see if object length matches and character count matches - then return true

```
            const stripChar = (str) => 
            {
               return str.replace(/[\W]/g,'').toLowerCase();
            }
            const charMap = str => {
                 let MAP = {};
                 for (let char of stripChar(str)) {
                     !MAP[char] ? (MAP[char] = 1) : MAP[char]++;
                 }
              return MAP;
            };

      const anagram = (str1, str2) => {
 if(Object.keys(charMap(str1)).length!==Object.keys(charMap(str2)).length) return false;
          for(let char in charMap(str1))
          {
            if(charMap(str1)[char]!==charMap(str2)[char]) return false;
          }
          return true;
        };

    console.log(anagram("rail safety","!f%airy tales"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is quite easy and simple.**

```
function checkAnagrams(str1, str2){

  var newstr1 = str1.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join();
  var newstr2 = str2.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join();

  if(newstr1 == newstr2){
    console.log("String is Anagrams");
  }
  else{
    console.log("String is Not Anagrams");
  }

}

checkAnagrams("Hello", "lolHe");
checkAnagrams("Indian", "nIndisn");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //The best code so far that checks, white space, non alphabets 
 //characters 
 //without sorting   
function anagram(stringOne,stringTwo){
var newStringOne = ""
var newStringTwo = ''
for(var i=0; i<stringTwo.length; i++){
 if(stringTwo[i]!= ' ' && isNaN(stringTwo[i]) == true){
    newStringTwo =  newStringTwo+stringTwo[i]
 }
    }

for(var i=0; i<stringOne.length; i++){
    if(newStringTwo.toLowerCase().includes(stringOne[i].toLowerCase())){
    newStringOne=newStringOne+stringOne[i].toLowerCase()
    }
}
console.log(newStringOne.length, newStringTwo.length)
if(newStringOne.length==newStringTwo.length){
    console.log("Anagram is === to   TRUE")
}
else{console.log("Anagram is === to   FALSE")}
}
anagram('ddffTTh@@@#$', '@dfT9t@D@#H$F')
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why your solution work above the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

```
function anagrams(str1,str2){

      //spliting string into array   
      let arr1 = str1.split("");
      let arr2 = str2.split("");

      //verifying array lengths
      if(arr1.length !== arr2.length){
          return false;
      }     

      //creating objects
      let frqcounter1={};
      let frqcounter2 ={};

    //   looping through array elements and keeping count
      for(let val of arr1){
         frqcounter1[val] =(frqcounter1[val] || 0) + 1; 
      }
      for(let val of arr2){
         frqcounter2[val] =(frqcounter2[val] || 0) + 1; 
      }

      console.log(frqcounter1);
      console.log(frqcounter2);

      //loop for every key in first object
      for(let key in frqcounter1){
          //if second object does not contain same frq count
          if(frqcounter2[key] !== frqcounter1[key]){
            return false;
          }
      }
      return true;

    }

    anagrams('anagrams','nagramas');
```

Comment: You don't need to split the strings just to check length and iterate. Just use the strings themselves!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest Algorithm

```js
    const isAnagram = (str1, str2) => {
            if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
                return false
            }
            const obj = {}
            for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
                const letter = str1[i]
                obj[letter] ? obj[letter] += 1 : obj[letter] = 1
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
                const letter = str2[i]
                if (!obj[letter]) {
                    return false
                }
                else {
                    obj[letter] -= 1
                }
            }
            return true
        }
        console.log(isAnagram('lalalalalalalalala', 'laalallalalalalala'))
        console.time('1')
        isAnagram('lalalalalalalalala', 'laalallalalalalala') // about 0.050ms
        console.timeEnd('1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const anagram = (strA, strB) => {
const buildAnagram = (str) => {
    const charObj = {};

    for(let char of str.replace(/[^\w]/g).toLowerCase()) {
        charObj[char] = charObj[char] + 1 || 1;
    }
    return charObj;
};

const strObjAnagramA = buildAnagram(strA);
const strObjAnagramB = buildAnagram(strB);

if(Object.keys(strObjAnagramA).length !== Object.keys(strObjAnagramB).length) {
    console.log(strA + ' and ' + strB + ' is not an anagram');
    return false;
}

for(let char in strObjAnagramA) {
    if(strObjAnagramA[char] !== strObjAnagramB[char]) {
        console.log(strA + ' and ' + strB + ' is not an anagram');
        return false;
    }
}
return true; } //console.log(anagram('Mary','Arms')); - false
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Oriol & Raja Sekar answers are fantastic, one is very simple and the other has excellent performance.

I remember this as an exercise when I was studying, so I got nostalgic and I tried to make my own version. While it was not my first goal, I ended up with a version that is a mix of both that seems to have an even better performance than the Raja Sekar'version. This difference in performance is even bigger when comparing bigger strings.

The key is to avoid extra iterations by using indexOf and using the found index to replace with null, so it will not be needed to count or sort at all.
So I called isAnagramIndexOfAndSuppressValue.

I guess it is a very interesting mechanism that could work in other scenarios.

So I built a performance test including some other answers approaches (either by relevance by the number of votes, performance simplicity of just because its answer claimed to be faster), so you do not have to.

NOTE: results will take a bit to be displayed due 10_000 times per function checking a few anagrams.

```js
function isAnagramSortOriol(a, b) {
    let str1 = a.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');
    let str2 = b.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');
    return str1 === str2;
}

function isAnagramRajaSekar(str1, str2) {

    if (str1 === str2) {
        return true;
    }

    let srt1Length = str1.length;
    let srt2Length = str2.length;

    if (srt1Length !== srt2Length) {
        return false;
    }

    var counts = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < srt1Length; i++) {
        let index = str1.charCodeAt(i) - 97;
        counts[index] = (counts[index] || 0) + 1;
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < srt2Length; j++) {
        let index = str2.charCodeAt(j) - 97;
        if (!counts[index]) {
            return false;
        }
        counts[index]--;
    }

    return true;
}

function isAnagramIndexOfAndSuppressValue(a, b) {
    if (a === b) {
        return true;
    }

    if (a.length !== b.length) {
        return false;
    }

    const longerChars = b.split("");
    for (const char of a) {
        const index = longerChars.indexOf(char);
        if (index === -1) {
            return false;
        }
        longerChars[index] = undefined;
    }
    return true;
}

function isAnagramAnnaVlasenko(str1, str2) {
    if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
        return false
    }
    const obj = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        const letter = str1[i]
        obj[letter] ? obj[letter] += 1 : obj[letter] = 1
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
        const letter = str2[i]
        if (!obj[letter]) {
            return false
        }
        else {
            obj[letter] -= 1
        }
    }
    return true
}

function isAnagramDanielBh(s, t) {
    if (s === t) return true
    if (s.length !== t.length) return false

    let count = {}

    for (let letter of s)
        count[letter] = (count[letter] || 0) + 1

    for (let letter of t) {
        if (!count[letter]) return false
        else --count[letter]
    }

    return true;
}

function isAnagramCamiloRodriguez(word1, word2) {
    const { length } = word1

    if (length !== word2.length) {
        return false
    }

    const charCounts = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        const char1 = word1[i]
        const char2 = word2[i]

        charCounts[char1] = (charCounts[char1] || 0) + 1
        charCounts[char2] = (charCounts[char2] || 0) - 1
    }

    for (const char in charCounts) {
        if (charCounts[char]) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

function areAnagramsWallaceSidhree(a, b) {
    // if length is not the same the words can't be anagrams
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;
    // make words comparable
    a = a.split("").sort().join("");
    b = b.split("").sort().join("");
    // check if each character match before proceeding
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if ((a.charAt(i)) != (b.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // all characters match!
    return true;
};

function AnagramsWesleyAC(str1 = '', str2 = '') {
    if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    if (str1 === str2) {
        return true;
    }

    const lookup = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        const char1 = str1[i];
        const char2 = str2[i];
        const remainingChars = str1.length - (i + 1);

        lookup[char1] = (lookup[char1] || 0) + 1;
        lookup[char2] = (lookup[char2] || 0) - 1;

        if (lookup[char1] > remainingChars || lookup[char2] > remainingChars) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        if (lookup[str1[i]] !== 0 || lookup[str2[i]] !== 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function test(fn) {
    const pairOfWords = [['abcdefghijkmlnpo', 'obcdefghijkmlnpa'], ['aba', 'baa'], ['god', 'dog'], ['this', 'that']];
    const start = performance.now();
    pairOfWords.forEach(([a, b]) => fn(a, b))
    const time = performance.now() - start
    return [fn.name, time];
}

const results = {}
const functions = [
    isAnagramAnnaVlasenko,
    isAnagramDanielBh,
    isAnagramIndexOfAndSuppressValue,
    isAnagramRajaSekar,
    isAnagramCamiloRodriguez,
    areAnagramsWallaceSidhree,
    AnagramsWesleyAC,
    isAnagramSortOriol
];

const iterations = 10_000;

for (const fn of functions) {
    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        const [name, time] = test(fn)
        results[name] = [...(results[name] || []), time];
    }
}

const averages = []
for (const name in results) {
    const times = results[name];
    const sum = times.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, 0)
    averages.push([name, sum / times.length]);
}

averages.sort(([aName, aAvg], [bName, bAvg]) => aAvg > bAvg ? 1 : -1)

console.log(`Average from ${iterations} iterations`, averages);
console.table(averages);
```