# Javascript anagram algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have recently started learning data structures and algorithms. I wanted to check if my anagram algorithm is efficient. And is there any tips you could provide,

```
function anagram(str1,str2){
let stringOne={};
let stringTwo={};
if(str1.length!==str2.length){
    return false
  }

for( let i=0; i<str1.length; i++){
    let char =str1[i];
    if(stringOne[char]){
        stringOne[char]++
    }else{

        stringOne[char]=1;            
    }   
}

 for( let i=0; i<str2.length; i++){
    let char =str2[i];
    if(stringTwo[char]){
        stringTwo[char]++
    }else{

        stringTwo[char]=1;            
    }

 }    


//compare the objects 
const compare=(obj1,obj2)=>{
    for( let el in obj1){
        if(obj1[el]!==obj2[el]){
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

return compare(stringOne,stringTwo) }
```

Comment: For the most efficient and also cleaner solution check https://stackoverflow.com/a/49496335/9819146 If you want only clean code then see top answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23785653/9819146